# Remove script tags inside p tags using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have written a code such that it extracts contents from paragraphs

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
import re


soup = BeautifulSoup(open('MUFC.html'))
a_tag = soup.find_all('p')
#print(a_tag)
for x in a_tag:
    print(x.get_text())
```

But there are some script tags inside p tags

something like

```
<p>
<script>
.....
</script>
</p>
```

which I don't want.
Can we put some condition so as to ignore  tags for get_text() method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, [remove](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) all `script` tags and then get the text:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('MUFC.html'))

for script in soup.find_all('script'):
    script.extract()

paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
for paragraph in paragraphs:
    print(paragraph.get_text(strip=True))
```